# Hibernate One-to-one mapping not working because of java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-one

I have Portfolio which can have InvestmentAllocation. I want to be able to set an InvestmentAllocation to Portfolio objects and fetch them easily, so I want the Portfolio class to contain information about its InvestmentAllocation. I also do not need an information about the Portfolio in InvestmentAllocation class, so there I want only to be able to see the @Column(name = "PortfolioKey") private Long portfolioId;

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Portfolio")
public class Portfolio extends MutableEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6668016124280143515L;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "PortfolioKey",
            nullable = false,
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false
    )
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private InvestmentAllocation investmentAllocation;

    @PostPersist
    protected void postPersist() {
        if (this.investmentAllocation != null) {
            if (this.investmentAllocation.getPortfolioId() == null) {
                this.investmentAllocation.setPortfolioId(this.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "InvestmentAllocation")
public class InvestmentAllocation extends MutableEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974811107021515065L;

    @Column(name = "PortfolioKey")
    private Long portfolioId;

    @Column(name = "Cash")
    private double cash;

    @Column(name = "Bond")
    private double bond;
}
```

Please find below how I created my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PortfolioGeneric] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvestmentAllocation](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PortfolioKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Bond] [decimal](8, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Cash] [decimal](8, 4) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvestmentAllocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvestmentAllocation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_InvestmentAllocation_Portfolio] FOREIGN KEY([PortfolioKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Portfolio] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvestmentAllocation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [PK_InvestmentAllocation_Portfolio]
GO
```

When I run the code, I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'PortfolioKey'.

**Why I am getting this error?
Is my one-to-one mapping not correct?**

Comment: Please check the InvestmentAllocation class, It is not (yet) perfect JPA entity. 1. No Entity annotation 2. No empty constructor 3. No ID annotation and id property. 4. No getters/setters

Comment: Edited, it's a copy mistake

Comment: Please also add the code snippet where you are getting error and the exception stack trace.

Comment: Aside... `decimal(8,4)` is quite small, this limits you to `declare @example1 decimal(8,4) = 9999.9999`. If you tried to `declare @example2 decimal(8,4) = 10000.0000`, for example, you'd get an error message like: _Msg 8115 Level 16 State 8 Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric._

Answer (score 0):

I changed the key to be in Portfolio table and removed the foreign key column from InvestmentAllocation and it worked.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "InvestmentAllocationKey", referencedColumnName = "id")
private InvestmentAllocation investmentAllocation;
```